# How is convolutional network used to locate logos in images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, image-processing

I have a large set of logos (think of it as kind of logos of automobile companies). Now, I want to train a convolutional network to locate the logo in a given image. Are there any papers that talk about locating simple objects in images?

I have the logos only for the training set and I want to locate these logos in the test phase with images that contain these logos anywhere in the image.

Comment: [Logo Recognition by Recursive Neural Networks](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.156.6975&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple approach to do that would be using a sliding window. More specifically:

1. You train a CNN or your classifier against $x \times x$ sized logos.
   (Maybe, you could add an extra class for random images as well)
2. Your images are larger than $x \times x$, so you will create a sliding window sized $x \times x$ to go all over your image.
3. The sliding window will be used as input in your classifier of step 1.
4. Therefore, it will output probabilities, which can help you locate the areas of interest. You could also use heat maps to visualise them.

This is a simple approach but it would work, if you are looking something more advanced you could have a look at papers like this: http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1842.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have only one kind of logo. So is it right that I have to use only  one node in the final layer? I am using 3 layers of convpool (conv + pool) and one fully connected layer. Then in the final layer there is only 1 node that outputs the probability that the logo is present in the input X x X region provided as input. The problem I am facing is I don't know what kind of output node should this final node be. Should it be sigmoid? Also, what kind of nodes should the other layers have? Should the convpool layers have a relu? Should the fully connected layers also have relu?

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar use one or two node(s) at the output layer. It doesn't really matter as long as cost function is appropriate to it. However, using 2 units (nodes) more common.  You can either use sigmoid or softmax for the output layer. Use ReLU in hidden layers to boost speed. It also eliminates pre-training (if you have enough data).

Comment: @yasin.yazici Thanks for the comment. Can you recommend the most appropriate cost function here in case of 1 and 2 output nodes? I was thinking of binary cross entropy in case of 1 node and min-squared error in case of 2 nodes. Is that the right way to think?

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar Actually I didn't mean much thing by 'appropriate' :). You can use both of them. I prefer 2 units with cross-entropy.